# Upper bound of an integral on a circle segment

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Say you have the integral:

$$\int_S f(z)dz = \int_S \frac{1}{x^{12}+1}dz$$

Where $S$ is a circle segment that runs from $R$ to $Re^{i\pi/6}$.  An example question suggests it is possible to estimate this integral with:

$$\left| \int_S f(z)dz \right| \le \frac{\pi R}{6} \frac1{R^{12}-1}$$

This looks like the length of the circle segment times the maximum possible value of $f(Re^{i\theta})$.

I think the maximum possible value because the triangle inequality says that, for a certain $|z|$, $|z+1|$ is largest when z lies on the positive real axis.  So for a given $R \gt 1$, $\frac1{R^{12}e^{i\theta}+1}$ cannot be larger than $\frac1{R^{12} -1}$.

Is this reasoning correct?  Is there a formal name or formula for the above estimate?

Comment: Yes, that's the reasoning. I know it as the standard estimate, $$\left\lvert \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz\right\rvert \leqslant L(\gamma)\cdot \sup \left\lbrace \lvert f(z)\rvert : z \in \operatorname{Tr}(\gamma)\right\rbrace.$$ Nowadays it's commonly called by a different name I always forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something called the ["$ML$" inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma), which states that the magnitude of a contour integral is bounded by the product of the maximum value of the magnitude of the integrand ($M$) times the length of the contour ($L$).

In your case, yes, sub $z=R e^{i \theta}$ to get

$$i R \int_0^{\pi/6} d\theta \, e^{i \theta}\, \frac{1}{R^{12} e^{i 12 \theta}+1}$$

The max value of the magnitude of the integrand is $1/(R^{12}-1)$ because the min value of the denominator occurs when $\theta=\pi/12$, which lies within the integration interval.  By the $ML$ inequality, the magnitude of the integral is bounded by

$$\frac{\pi}{6} R \frac{1}{R^{12}-1}$$